# Javascript new Image() dimensions

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have this object that is drawn to canvas but I cant seem to get the dimensions (width/height) of the image.

```
var rawr = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    speed: 4,
    height:0,
    img: new Image(),
    url: "https://www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo11w.png",
    init: function() { 
        this.img.src=this.url; 
        this.height=this.img.height;
    },
    draw: function() { 
        canvas.drawImage(this.img,this.x,this.y);
    },
    move: function() {
        if(this.y>CANVAS_HEIGHT)
        {
        this.y=this.height*-1;
        }
        this.y+=this.speed;
    }
};
```

Basically, `this.height` remains zero, as initially defined. How do I correct this?

Thanks in advance,
Tim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wait for the onload of the image to trigger before you leverage its height.  Something like this:

```
var imagePreloaded = this.img;
imagePreloaded.onload(function(){
   var height = imagePreloaded.height;
})
```

Comment: I've marked this as the correct answer because it's almost the solution I need. If I `alert(imagePreloaded.height)` I get the result i need but when trying `this.height=imagePreloaded.height;` it doesn't seem to set the value. Any suggestions?

Comment: `this` is in a different scope inside that anonymous function.

Answer (score 3):

If I am reading this correctly, you are inspecting the height immediately after setting the src.  Try doing that in an onLoad event handler so that it waits for the image to load and then sizes the image tag, otherwise it doesn't know the height.